# "quotation", added John -- Quotative subject-verb inversion

Tags: word-order

Which of the following is correct? And if both, then which is preferred?

1. "Blah blah blah", added (or mentioned, commented etc) Mr.John.
2. "Blah blah blah", Mr.John added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so this is called a subjct-verb inversion, and the first option is generally preferred, but both are correct.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93verb_inversion_in_English http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=1848